# Upgrade my code in jquery 1.4.4 to 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, upgrade

I have popup window below code and code is working fine with jquery-1.4.4 but when i upgrade to jquery-1.10.2 it's not working can any body tell me where is the problem? I think some function changes can solve the problem but i don't know which one

```
(function($) {


    $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).prop('data-reveal-id');
        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
    });


    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {


        var defaults = {  
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
            animationspeed: 300, 
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' 
        }; 

        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

            var modal = $(this),
                topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
                topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
                locked = false,
                modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

            if(modalBG.length == 0) {
                modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
            }           


            //Entrance Animations
            modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
              modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
                $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
                if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    }
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    } 
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                        unlockModal()               
                    }
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:open');
            });     

            //Closing Animation
            modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
              if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                            modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                    }       
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:close');
            });     


            //Open Modal Immediately
        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

            //Close Modal Listeners
            var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });

            if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
                modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
                modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                  modal.trigger('reveal:close')
                });
            }
            $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
            });



            function unlockModal() { 
                locked = false;
            }
            function lockModal() {
                locked = true;
            }   

        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The first problem is the deprecated/removed `live` method, use `on` instead.

Comment: This ^ I'd suggest using jQuery migrate to flag deprecated code in the console.